# Why is KE equal to PE for waves on a string? Clarification needed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, continuum-mechanics, string

For waves on a string **why** is [Kinetic Energy said to be equal to Potential Energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/327329/139621)? The linked answer gives no reason for it.

I knew that KE for each elementary part of wave is $(1/2)(dm)v^2$ ($v$ i.e. $\frac{dy}{dt}$ being instantaneous velocity) while PE is $T\Delta \ell$ (as in the linked answer).

Comment: If you define PE=0 when the string is at rest then any change in PE must be balanced by an equal but opposite change in KE in order to conserve energy...

Comment: @Farcher That answer doesn't answer my query.

Comment: I have the proof for the example given in the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

**Kinetic Energy Of Plane Progressive Wave In A String:**

Consider a small element of the string at a distance $x$ from origin $dx$.

K.E of that small part of the string is: $$\frac{1}{2}(\mu dx)(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2$$

**Potential Energy Of Plane Progressive Wave In A String:**

Again consider a small element of the string at a distance $x$ from origin $dx$.

Since there is no motion in the x-direction, points on the string only move
in the y-direction. If the slope of a segment changes, the length must also
change. Since it takes work to stretch the string, there is also potential energy stored in the string. The change in length of a segment is:

$$dl = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} − dx ≈ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{∂y}{∂x})^2dx$$

Hence, potential energy of that small part of the string is:

$$Tdl=T\left(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{∂y}{∂x})^2dx\right)$$

---

Hence, for unit length of string:

$$K_l=\frac{1}{2}(\mu)(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2$$

$$U_l=T\left(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{∂y}{∂x})^2\right)$$

If $y=f(x \pm vt)$ (general solution of wave equation for travelling waves)

$$K_l=\frac{1}{2}(\mu)v^2(f')^2$$

$$U_l=\frac{1}{2}T(f')^2$$

Now using, $v^2=\frac{T}{\mu}$ we can easily see that $K_l=U_l$.

Note that this result is only true for a single travelling wave; it is not true if waves travelling in both directions are present!

Source: http://mpalffy.lci.kent.edu/Optics/Chapters/Ch1_Waves_on_a_String.pdf

Comment: Take note that $y = f(x \pm vt)$ is NOT the general solution of the wave equation, since it only describes traveling waves.  The general solution is a superposition of such waves, and can be formulated as this : \begin{equation}y(t, x) = \frac{1}{2}\big( f(x - vt) + f(x + vt) \big) + \frac{1}{2 v} \int_{x - vt}^{x + vt} g(u) \, du, \end{equation} where $g(u)$ describes the  initial derivative (or "velocity") of the wave.

Comment: Would this be also the case for a single traveling wave on, say, a spring? Or is $KE = U$ specific to a string?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why the KE should be equal to the PE, for a wave on a string, except for some special time (like a mass oscillating on a spring).  For example, consider a simple *stationary wave* on a string.  At some time, the whole string is *instantly straight* (at this time : PE = 0 since there is no deformation of the string, *at that particular moment*), while each part of the string is in motion (KE != 0).  Thus clearly KE != PE at that moment in time (instantaneously straight string while the wave is still propagating on it).

However, KE + PE = cste (conservation of total energy), if there is no exterior agent.

This is very similar to the simpler case of a single mass oscillating on a vertical spring.  At some moment in time, you may get $K = U$, but at another moment you'll also have $U = 0$ and $K = K_{\text{max}}$, while $E \equiv K + U = \textit{cste}$ at *any* moment.

**EDIT :**  For a general wave (of wave function $y(t, x)$) on a string with fixed extremities : $y(t, 0) = y(t, L) = 0$, it is easy to use integration by parts and the wave equation to show the following :

Total kinetic energy :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
K = \int_0^L \frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \Big)^2 \, \lambda \, dx.
\end{equation}
Total potential energy (notice that $v^2 = T/\lambda$) :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
U = \int_0^L \frac{v^2}{2} \Big( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \Big)^2 \, \lambda \, dx.
\end{equation}
Wave equation :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\frac{1}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 \, y}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \, y}{\partial x^2} = 0.
\end{equation}
Thus integration by parts gives this relation :
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
U = K - \frac{\lambda}{4} \, \frac{d^2 \, }{d t^2} \int_0^L y^2(t, x) \, dx.
\end{equation}
So if the area below the string stays constant while the wave propagates (or more precisely the area of the function $y^2(t, x)$), the last term cancels and you do get $U = K$.  In the simple case of an impulse propagating on the string (sinusoidal wave, for example), the area is conserved, so $U = K$.  This is a special case though.  In the case of a stationary wave, the area isn't conserved and $U \ne K$.

Comment: Did you see the answer I linked? Is that wrong, then?

Comment: I guess that answer you linked is false.  KE isn't always equal to PE.  Also, don't confuse *energy density* and *energy*.  KE and PE are *integrals* on the string's length.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: For the example given in the link the kinetic energy is equal to the potential energy and there is no interchange between the two. There is proof in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Comments for a uniform harmonic string:

1. For a transversal xor longitudinal left- xor right-mover $f(x\pm vt)$, it is straightforward exercise to check directly that the kinetic energy density $\frac{\mu v^2}{2} (f^{\prime}(x\pm vt))^2$ matches the potential energy density, and hence
   $$KE=PE.\tag{1}$$
2. Eq. (1) is not necessarily true for superpositions thereof because of cross-terms, but it does hold in time average due to the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem).